# How to set goals in a ColdFusion bullet chart?

Tags: charts, coldfusion, cfml, zingchart

Bullet charts are [supported in ColdFusion from version 10](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d31851852cc9f7d1353e88b409-7fda.html), but I can't find any documentation that explains how to use it from cfml code. I want to know how to set up the goals on a series in cfml.

This is a minimal bullet chart in cfml:

```
<cfchart
    format="html"
    type="bullet">

  <cfchartseries serieslabel="Foo">
    <cfchartdata item="Bar 1" value="1000">
    <cfchartdata item="Bar 2" value="2000">
  </cfchartseries>

</cfchart>
```

ColdFusion is using the [ZingChart](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/chart-types/bullet-charts/) library under the hood and this is how you can set goals in js:

```
{
  "type": "bullet",
  "series": [
    {
      "values": [20,40,25,50,15,45,33,34],
      "goals": [25,43,30,40,21,59,35,31]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have looked into the ColdFusion server tags definitions trying to figure out if there is an special attribute or tag to define the series goals, nothing.

```
\WEB-INF\cftags\META-INF\taglib.cftld
```

Comment: Why not just use the ZingCharts example and build it with JS, instead of cfchart?

Comment: Charts are graphical representations of data.  Data can be anything.  In your case, it's goals.  Read this.  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec1260e-7fef.html

Comment: @DanBracuk - Sure, but not seeing how that addresses the issue with this specific chart. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking again into the *taglib.cftld* file I figured out the attributes supported by **cfchartdata** tag:

- item
- value
- **zValue**

The solution for CF11+ is to use the zValue attribute to specify the value of the goal on each data point:

```
<cfchart
    format="html"
    type="bullet">

  <cfchartseries serieslabel="Foo">
    <cfchartdata item="Bar 1" value="1000" zValue="800">
    <cfchartdata item="Bar 2" value="2000" zValue="2500">
  </cfchartseries>

</cfchart>
```

Comment: Nice follow up. Just for reference, are you actually running CF10 or 11? A quick test works with CF11, but not 10: http://trycf.com/gist/f1cb47bd7d6bcef7a4352f52075f06c9/acf11?theme=monokai

Comment: I'm running cf2016, and yes the zValue it is not working on cf10.

Comment: Thanks for the confirm.  I added a note about version (for the next guy).